# MapReduce Program not reading the text beyond a limit

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to Hadoop and learning few mapreduce program. I was trying to read a CSV file using a Mapper class.
The CSV contains header and the values till 20 columns. The strange thing is while reading the CSV file the program was working
fine till the point where I am reading the 17th index but getting ArrayOutOfBondException.
I am not able to understand even though 18th index is present it is throwing the exception.

Here is my code:

```
package org.apress.prohadoop.c3;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apress.prohadoop.c3.CSVFileProcessor.LastFmConstants;

public class CSVFileProcessorNewAPI {

     protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CSVFileProcessorNewAPI.class);

    public class LastFmConstants {

        public static final int match_id = 0;
        public static final int inning_id= 1;
        public static final int batting_team = 2;
        public static final int bowling_team = 3;
        public static final int over = 4;
        public static final int ball = 5;
        public static final int batsman = 6;
        public static final int non_striker = 7;
        public static final int bowler = 8;
        public static final int is_super_over = 9;
        public static final int wide_runs = 10;
        public static final int total_runs_inOver=17;

        public static final int player_dismissed=18;
        public static final int dismissal_kind=19;
    }

    public static class MyMapper extends MapReduceBase 
                                 implements  Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {


        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
                        OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, 
                        Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

            logger.info("Vibhas Logger Started");

            try {
                if ((key).get() == 0 && value.toString().contains("header") /*Some condition satisfying it is header*/)
                    return;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String[] parts = value.toString().split("[,]");

            String inning_id=parts[LastFmConstants.inning_id];
            String match_id_=parts[LastFmConstants.match_id];
            String batting_team=parts[LastFmConstants.batting_team];
            String bowling_team=parts[LastFmConstants.bowling_team];
            String over=parts[LastFmConstants.over];
            String ball=parts[LastFmConstants.ball];
            String batsman=parts[LastFmConstants.batsman];
            String non_striker=parts[LastFmConstants.non_striker];
            String bowler=parts[LastFmConstants.bowler];
            String wide_runs=parts[LastFmConstants.wide_runs];
            String total_runs_inOver=parts[LastFmConstants.total_runs_inOver];
            String player_Dismissed=parts[LastFmConstants.player_dismissed];
            String dismissal_kind=parts[LastFmConstants.dismissal_kind];

            if(!bowler.isEmpty() && bowler.trim().contains("Chahal")   && dismissal_kind.equalsIgnoreCase("S Dhawan")){
                int runs=Integer.parseInt(total_runs_inOver);
        output.collect(new Text("Match-->"+match_id_), new IntWritable(runs));
        }
        }
    }

    public static class MyReducer extends MapReduceBase 
                                  implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
        public void reduce(Text key, 
                           Iterator<IntWritable> values,
                           OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, 
                           Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
            logger.info("Vibhas Reducer Started");
            int sum = 0;
            while (values.hasNext()) {
                sum += values.next().get();
            }
            output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JobConf conf = new JobConf(CSVFileProcessorNewAPI.class);
        conf.setJobName("CSVFileProcessorNewAPI Job");

        conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        conf.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
        conf.setCombinerClass(MyReducer.class);
        conf.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);
        conf.setNumReduceTasks(1);
        conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
        conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

        JobClient.runJob(conf);
    }
}
```

CSV File format:

```
match_id,inning,batting_team,bowling_team,over,ball,batsman,non_striker,bowler,is_super_over,wide_runs,bye_runs,legbye_runs,noball_runs,penalty_runs,batsman_runs,extra_runs,total_runs,player_dismissed,dismissal_kind,fielder

1,1,Sunrisers Hyderabad,Royal Challengers Bangalore,1,1,DA Warner,S Dhawan,TS Mills,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,

1,1,Sunrisers Hyderabad,Royal Challengers Bangalore,1,2,DA Warner,S Dhawan,TS Mills,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,
```

Exception:

```
hadoop jar /home/cloudera/Downloads/pro-apache-hadoop-master/prohadoop.jar org.apress.prohadoop.c3.CSVFileProcessorNewAPI /Input/test.csv /outPutCSV
18/03/15 02:19:19 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
18/03/15 02:19:20 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
18/03/15 02:19:20 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
18/03/15 02:19:20 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
18/03/15 02:19:20 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
18/03/15 02:19:21 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1520413460063_0042
18/03/15 02:19:21 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1520413460063_0042
18/03/15 02:19:21 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1520413460063_0042/
18/03/15 02:19:21 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1520413460063_0042
18/03/15 02:19:27 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1520413460063_0042 running in uber mode : false
18/03/15 02:19:27 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
18/03/15 02:19:43 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 50% reduce 0%
18/03/15 02:19:45 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1520413460063_0042_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 18
    at org.apress.prohadoop.c3.CSVFileProcessorNewAPI$MyMapper.map(CSVFileProcessorNewAPI.java:77)
    at org.apress.prohadoop.c3.CSVFileProcessorNewAPI$MyMapper.map(CSVFileProcessorNewAPI.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:459)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1917)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

Kindly help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should split the `String` via below command, and you will be all set:

```
String[] parts = value.toString().split(",", -1);
```

Adding `-1` in the second parameter ensures that you are going to retain empty string at the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

It is dangerous to do `String[] parts = value.toString().split("[,]");` and then assume that every single record you get will have the correct number of columns. Especially when dealing with large amounts of data, the likelihood of receiving "dirty" data is something that cannot be ignored. It only takes one bad row and your entire job dies.

You should instead do a check:

```
String[] parts = value.toString().split(",", -1);
if (parts != null && parts.length == 20) {
    //your normal logic  
} else {
    logger.warn("Unparseable record identified: {}", value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will implement the same.